# How to move my gists from one account to another?

Tags: github, gist

I have a lot of github gists on one account and I want to move them to my main account. How do I do that? Surely I'm not the first to want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use the [GitHub API for Gists](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists), in order to:

- [list gists for one account](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#list-gists),
- for each gist:

  - clone it via the URL provided by `git_pull_url`.
  - [create an empty gist](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#create-a-gist) on your target account
  - push the local gist repo to the newly create empty gist via the URL provided by `git_push_url`.

Comment: yeah, so is there something already made to do that for me? I guess it shouldn't take me long to do it myself but I would rather not...

Comment: @Spacemonkey The download part does exists: https://gist.github.com/tjmaynes/fd9c68152fd9229e10b6. I am looking for the upload part (maybe a bit like https://gist.github.com/jhbot/1101382). But you will still have to do some scripting.

Comment: the download script wants all my gists to be public, but mine are all private, so I would need to make them all public first. It seems like I'll end up writing a script to use the API

Comment: @Spacemonkey yes, there is still work to be done, like including a OAuth token (https://gist.github.com/caspyin/2288960#oauth)